# Find closest in value to the median of S

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given an unsorted array A[1....N], trying to find the K numbers in A that are closes in value to the median of A. I can find the median of A in linear time O(N). Can I also find K in linear time?? for example. A = [9,2,7,3,8,1,12}, Median(A) = 7, and 3 items with closes values to 7 are {7,8,9}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) such as [Introselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect).  If you happen to be implementing in c++, you can use the very useful [std::nth_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element)

It will rearrange a sequence of elements such that all elements before a given point are less than those elements that follow.  Do this twice and you've got your set of K elements that are closest to the mean.